# The bounty gambit: Is it misuse to add e.g. a 50-point bounty aiming to attract >5 upvotes?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

On some of my posts (like [this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44329/did-depressed-people-far-more-accurately-estimate-how-many-monsters-they-killed)) I feel like it would be worthwhile playing **the bounty gambit**: *add a bounty with the sole aim of getting those points back and more in upvotes*.  E.g. a 50-point bounty gambit needs to attract >5 upvotes to succeed.

**Question**: Is it misuse to add e.g. a 50-point bounty aiming to attract >5 upvotes?

It's somewhat unscrupulous: I have no reason to do this other than potentially gaining more reputation than I lose, and perhaps it's a bit disruptive.

Comment: It's notable that this gambit would only really play since the question upvote gain was unleashed to 10 instead of 5 since years. I believe there was a really conscious brain behind makeing these fine tunes in rep calculation.

Comment: Okay, gambit played.  Wish me luck!  Haha (:

Comment: Argh!  It's not working.  Someone downvoted me.

Comment: It is pretty simple: to the *quality* folks, *anything* you do to gain reputation must be devil's spawn. Yeah, when the motivation is "reputation", how dare you come here. Whereas for the gamer folks, anything is *fair game*. But thing is: when you start to put out bounties in ways that seem to only be advertizing your own content, sooner or later your readers will figure that. And then that equation about receiving upvotes will cease to work.

Comment: For my question, I was predicting the “quality” folks would be unwilling to vote based on “meta” reasons. But in any case, it’s still a pretty amazing answer, so I’m not too unhappy to take a hit.